# Group Django commands to a folder inside the same app

Tags: python, django, django-commands, django-command-extensions

Is it allowed to group custom Django commands to separate folders inside the same Django app?

I have a lot of them and wanted to group them logically by purpose. Created folders but Django can't find them.

Maybe I'm trying to run them wrong. Tried:

- `python manage.py process_A_related_data`
- the same plus imported all commands in `__init__.py`
- `python manage.py folderA process_A_related_data`
- `python manage.py folderA.process_A_related_data`
- `python manage.py folderA/process_A_related_data`

Got following error:

```
Unknown command: 'folderA/process_A_related_data'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. is answer to your question how to have django commands in different folders rather than a `management/commands`?

Comment: @Glyphack I want to group them inside `management/commands`. Like for example: `management/commands/folderA`, `management/commands/folderB`, etc. When I move them to these folders and import in `__init__.py` - I see exception shown above.

Answer (score 9):

I think you can create a basic custom command which will run other commands from relevent folders. Here is an approach you can take:

First make a folder structure like this:

```
management/
    commands/
       folder_a/
          process_A_related_data.py
       folder_b/
          process_A_related_data.py
       process_data.py
```

Then inside `process_data.py`, update the command like this:

```
from django.core import management
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

import importlib

class Command(BaseCommand):
   help = 'Folder Process Commands'

   def add_arguments(self, parser):
       parser.add_argument('-u', '--use', type=str, nargs='?', default='folder_a.process_A_related_data')
    
   def handle(self, *args, **options):
       try:
           folder_file_module = options['use'] if options['use'].startswith('.') else '.' + options['use']
           command = importlib.import_module(folder_file_module, package='your_app.management.commands')
           management.call_command(command.Command())
       except ModuleNotFoundError:
           self.stderr.write(f"No relevent folder found: {e.name}")
```

Here I am using [**`call_command`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django.core.management.call_command) method to call other managment commands.

Then run commands like this:

```
python manage.py process_data --use folder_a.process_A_related_data
```

Finally, if you want to run commands like `python manage.py folder_a.process_A_related_data`, then probably you need to change in `manage.py`. Like this:

```
import re
...

try:
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
except ImportError as exc:
    raise ImportError(
        "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
        "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
        "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
    ) from exc

if re.search('folder_[a-z].*', sys.argv[-1]):
    new_arguments = sys.argv[:-1] + ['process_data','--use', sys.argv[-1]]
    execute_from_command_line(new_arguments)
else:
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Will test later to check, but looks like this should achieve the goal.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to partition the code by using mixins (I have not tried this in this context, though)

A standard management command looks like

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
   help = 'FIXME A helpful comment goes here'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument( 'name', ...)
        # more argument definitions

    def handle(self, *args, **options):  
        # do stuff
```

Which can probably be replaced by a "stub" in `app/management/commands`:

```
from wherever.commands import FooCommandMixin
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand    
class Command(FooCommandMixin, BaseCommand): 
    # autogenerated -- do not put any code in here!
    pass
```

and in wherever/commands

```
class FooCommandMixin( object):
   help = 'FIXME A helpful comment goes here'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument( 'name', ...)
        # more argument definitions

    def handle(self, *args, **options):  
        # do the work
```

It would not be hard to write a script to go through a list of file names or paths (using glob.glob) using re.findall to identify appropriate class declarations, and to (re)generate a matching stub for each in the app's management/commands folder.

Also/instead Python's argparse allows for [the definition of sub-commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands). So you should be able to define a command that works like

```
./manage.py foo bar --aa --bb something --cc  and
./manage.py foo baz --bazzy a b c
```

where the syntax after foo is determined by the next word (bar or baz or ...). Again I have no experience of using subcommands in this context.

Comment: As I understood, you propose to create command which will be a "runner" for my subcommands using first argument as name for command, correct?

Comment: Yes, argparse subcommands ought to let you have one management command with the next word determining what to do and what  syntax applies. You could then dispatch in the "top" `handle` method to functions or mixins whose code is located elsewhere, and these do the work. I've never tried subcomands in this context, though.

Answer (score 0):

I found no mention of support for this feature in the release notes. It looks to be that this is still not supported as of version Django 3.0. I would suggest that you use meaningful names for your files that help you specify. You could always come up w/ a naming convention!

Comment: Meaningful naming convention will not help, as it is still not convenient to work with big list of files in a single folder in IDE.

Comment: @bitzbytes why from version 3.0? What was changed? Did you mean version of Django or Python?

Comment: @wowkin2 as of version 3.0 of Django. They still have no support for the feature you are requesting. You can see a similar question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12792335/11599472 I guess if you really needed to, you could take on the advice given here.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'm looking for patch like described there.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be: create a specific Django "satellite" app for each group of management commands.

In recent version of Django, the requirements for a Python module to be an app are minimal: you won't need to provide any fake models.py or other specific files as happened in the old days.

While far from perfect from a stylistic point of view, you still gain a few advantages:

- no need to hack the framework at all
- `python manage.py` will list the commands grouped by app
- you can control the grouping by providing suitable names to the apps
- you can use these satellite apps as container for specific unit tests

I always try to avoid fighting against the framework, even when this means to compromise, and sometimes accept it's occasional design limitations.

Comment: In that case, I'll get a lot of redundant apps. About "always try to avoid fighting against the framework" - you are totally right. That's why I'm looking for right tool for that.

Comment: True ! I understand your suggestion, and agree on it, but ... 
You could surely succeed in partitioning the management commands in subfolders with some code twist, but please ask to yourself: will other "standard" management command still work with the new project layout ?
For example: will `makemessages` work ?  
Maybe yes, maybe no ;) You might face some headaches much later in the project development

Comment: But `makemessages` are running by `django-admin` not `manage.py` ;)

Comment: actually I'm looking for solution that will work and not break anything.

Comment: You can run any management command with `manage.py`; `django-admin` just provides a subset ... and notably `startproject` which is needed at the very beginning to generate the `manage.py` script ;) All in all, `makemessages` was just an example of a command which needs to navigate the project subfolders, and as such could get confused by an unexpected layout

Comment: "actually I'm looking for solution that will work and not break anything" sure, we always do ! and we also hope that it won't break anything with future versions of the framework